# If visited url contains #, do nothing, else redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, anchor

I want the visitors of my one-page horizontal website to be redirected to the part that is considered 'Home' (it's in the center of the body). Right now, when they visit the main URL, they will just see the most left part of the horizontal website.

The thing is, I want to be able to share other parts of the website by anchor link, without my visitors being redirected to the #Home anchor.

So what I basically want is:

- if the visited URL contains #, do nothing (since all anchor links contain #)
- if the visited URL does not contain #, redirect to the #Home anchor. (if it doesn't contain a #, I consider the url either invalid, or they are just visiting the homepage without an anchor in the URL.

Right now, I have this JS code:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') > -1){
    // do nothing   
}
else {
    top.location.href = "http://www.url.com/#Home";
}
```

What's wrong with this code, and how I should do this the proper way?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger? I see nothing obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: Yes, i did.. and, for example, the debugger in chrome thinks it's fine too :). I can't figure out what the issue is..

Comment: This is the working code (thanks to Akhil Sekharan and Cerbrus):

<code>
if(!!~window.location.href.indexOf('#')){
    //do nothing   
}
else

{
    $('[href="#Home"]').click();
location.href = location.href+ '#Home';
}
</code>

Comment: Next trick is to rewrite the addressbar when a link with an anchor has been clicked (since its a one-page website, there will be no reloading). But i will make a new question for that one. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have an anchor somewhere in your webpage called home. You can try emulating a click on it. Like:

```
$('[href="#Home"]').click();
location.href = location.href+ '#Home';
```

Comment: Yes, i can do that. The problem is that i do want the address bar to contain the full url (http://www.url.com/#Home) when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
if(!!~window.location.href.indexOf('#')){
    //do nothing   
}else{
    top.location.href = "http://www.url.com/#Home";
}
```

The `!!~` part will cast the result of `indexOf` to a proper boolean. (`!!` casts a true-ish or false-ish value to `true` and `false`, the tilde (`~`) converts the output of `ìndexOf` to a true-ish value if the string contains the needle (`"#"`))

This does reload the page for me, at the specified url, in Google Chrome.

Comment: This partially did the trick! Thanks! Too bad i can only set one of the answers as 'accepted'

Comment: Well, i'm new here, so i'm not allowed to give upvotes yet. But i will as soon as i am :)